# Issues in referencing new elements in an existing Android application

Tags: android, android-xml

I have an existing android app. I wanted to change its menu structure without disturbing the existing code. For this I added 2 new java files and relative xmls in the existing project and updated the manifest.xml with the new starter activity.

The issue which I am facing is in the java code. I am not able to reference the elements of the new xmls `xxx.findViewById(R.id.xxx)`
The error coming up: `cannot be resolved or is not a valid field`

Please suggest something, I am a newbee

Answer (score 0):

When you build an application, Android will create a file called "R.java". This file basically is an index to all resources in your project (strings, layouts, drawables, etc.). If you add new resources by hand, you cannot refer to these resources because they have no ID in the R class. 
According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) you can use the `aapt` tool to (re?)generate the R file, but I have no experience with this myself.